# Assiging an Array in afterModel to controller property gives Cannot delegate set error

Tags: ember.js

If I do this in a controller the addressList property is assigned.

```
addressList  : function () {
model.accounts.forEach(function (account) {
              addressList.push(account.get("address"));

          });
    return addressList;
  }.property(),
```

however if I do the same in the afterModel hook in the route:

```
   model.accounts.forEach(function (account) {
          addressList.push(account.get("address"));

        }
      });
      this.controllerFor("journey").set("addressList", addressList);
```

I get error:

```
Error while processing route: journey Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set(.. to the 'content' property of object proxy   ..  its 'content' is undefined.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no error or bug here. You are not supposed to set controller properties from the route. Your first implementation is the right way of doing things.

About the `afterModel` hook

> suited to performing logic that can only take place after the model has already resolved

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel

Any property that you define in your controller will be set *after the model has already resolved* too. So from that point of view it works the same way.

A use case for the `afterModel` hook is when there is a chance of that logic "failing" and as a result you need to redirect to another route.

Controllers are model decorators, that is where you want to set properties derived from your model data.

Comment: ok, is there a better way to get the 1st item in the array rather than using a foreach in my 1st method?

Comment: one reason I am using afterModel in the route is that there doesn't seem to be a hook in the contoller that runs after all the model data has been returned

Comment: You don't need a hook, you can just listen for a model change. Like: `addressList  : function () { ... }.property('model')`